# Modules loading despite being added to the blacklist

Tags: blacklist, modules

I'd like to blacklist a couple of modules, namely `drm`, `drm_kms_helper`, `i2c_algo_bit` and `i915` to forbid my integrated Intel GPU to be used, but to use my Nvidia MXM card instead.

I inserted the following lines into /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist i915
blacklist drm
blacklist drm_kms_helper
blacklist i2c_algo_bit
```

Despite the above right after rebooting my laptop and typing lsmod I can see these modules loaded.

Why does my blacklist get utterly disrespected and what can I do about it?

Comment: does this link help? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1468752

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After modifications in `/etc/modprobe`, you need to run:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I would be careful with disabling `drm` etc. I wouldn't be surprised if the nvidia driver depends on it (check with `modinfo nvidia`). Also, should you have any problems with your nvidia driver, then you will have a low resolution screen which might not support the GUI login at all.

Why would you disable the iGPU? The processor is already in use so I doubt if it saves any power or resources.

Comment: I wanted to deactivate the iGPU because I use the eGPU all the time and resume from suspend doesn't work.  I thought that if I can remove these modules then the iGPU won't activate upon resume and I'll be able to successfully resume my laptop.  Unfortunately, even though I can successfully blacklist the modules of the iGPU I cannot make resume work.

Comment: You should create a new question for that, please include your hardware with the exact model type if possible.

Comment: There's at least 5 blacklisting questions on here that could be answered by this.

Comment: @austinmarton Which one exactly? You can also flag a post for moderator attention if you feel that it is a duplicat.e

Comment: @Lekensteyn sorry I meant the other way round! Your answer above could SOLVE a number of unanswered questions about why blacklisting isn't working (that I stumbled across myself)

Comment: @austinmarton Oh yes, I understood that, but what I said still holds. Just flag them if you feel it is appropriate :)

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation to the OP, and heeding all of @Lekensteyn's good advice, `blacklist i915` silently appeared to do nothing for me, even though lsmod said nothing was using i915, but [install i915 /bin/false](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Using_files_in_.2Fetc.2Fmodprobe.d.2F_2) did the trick, causing Gnome 3 to automatically fall back to using llvmpipe.

Comment: I actually did: `install [module] /bin/true` Not sure what the difference is to /bin/false but it worked

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked on 16.04 LTS for i915.ko.

Even using `module_to_blacklist.blacklist=yes` or `modprobe.blacklist=module_to_blacklist` on the kernel commandline of grub did not work.

The (dirty) solution I found was to rename `/lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko` and `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so` and `/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so`

Unfortunately, external VGA screen is not recognized anymore :{