# How to Prevent users from copying files to usb..?

Tags: file-sharing, usb-drive, copy

using ubuntu 16.04lts,Some of the users are taking important files into their personal devices(pen drive or portable HDD). How to prevent users not to send or copy files to usb..?

users are using USB HEADSET it should work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe the scenario. Is it a Lab PC?

Comment: yeah it is a lab PC(Lenovo laptop)

Comment: Is preventing USB device at all valid answer? They can't copy both way.

Comment: yeah it is a valid one..preventing copy from both way, but users must able to use USB HEADSET(it should work).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to blacklist the USB storage driver. Users will not be able to read or write files through USB sticks. This not only protects your corporate information from theft but also reduces chances of viruses entering your system.

There isn't a single parameter for blacklisting USB storage because it can vary between kernel versions.

A good write up is on AskUbuntu: [how-do-i-disable-usb-storage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254113/how-do-i-disable-usb-storage) This Q&A covers Ubuntu 12.04 through 16.04. It covers different blacklisting methods and different USB storage driver names.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advice, but here the thing is...users are using USB HEADSET WITH MICROPHONE...if i blacklist USB STORAGE DRIVER..headset will work or not...?

Comment: You might have to block USB PTP/MTP (used by many phones & cameras) too, but that's implemented in userspace (`libgphoto`, `libmtp`, etc.), so you might want to remove those libraries.

Comment: @Mohammad USB headsets should not need the USB storage driver.

Comment: @JanC I believe you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Though blacklisting USB driver will work, but there is another good solution. You can prevent the users from mounting, unmounting partitions without giving root password. This way, administrators can use USB devices without having to un-blacklist the drivers first.

First create a file naming `disable-mounting-without-password.pkla`. The content of the file will be

```
[Disable mount without password]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-*
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=auth_admin
```

After saving it, move it to `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/` using this command (assuming you're in the same directory as the file)

```
sudo mv disable-mount-without-password.pkla /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/
```

Then restart the service using

```
sudo systemctl restart polkitd.service
```

Now, everytime a user wants to mount a partition, they'll be asked for the password, even for USB devices.