# Disable USB Mass Storage for root user

Tags: permissions

I want to disable USB access to root and enable it when it is required.

I need to restrict users to copy and paste anything using external drives.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “stranded user”?

Comment: I mean root user .

Answer (score 0):

```
modprobe -r usb-storage
```

will remove the `usb-storage` module and thus disable every usb storage device on the system.

To disable usb storage devices permanently, blacklist the module with

```
echo "blacklist usb-storage" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

(see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/254183/507051))

Comment: every time when i give this cmd , i got a FATAL error ."modprob :FATAL :Module usb_storage is in use ".

Comment: Well do you have usb storages attached? Try to remove them first.

Comment: If you also want to block it for root users, just rip out every usb slot not in use, this will block it for sure. ;)